# Can tmux be used in multi user environments safely?

Tags: shell, tmux

I could not find docs on how tmux clients and servers commmunicate. I would like to use tmux but it cannot be deployed if it only uses sockets for this. fifo's or pipes would be ok as long as fifo's are created in dir specfied by me. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tmux` is safe. It uses Unix domain sockets, which are located within the filesystem (specifically, `/var/run/tmux/tmux-$UID`) and use **standard Unix file permissions**: other users cannot connect to a Unix socket just like they cannot read a file.

```
# tree -pug /var/run/tmux
/var/run/tmux
└── [drwx------ grawity  utmp    ]  tmux-1004
    └── [srwxrwx--- grawity  grawity ]  default
```

You can specify your own path using `tmux -S path/to/socket`.

---

FIFOs cannot be used for this purpose since they are unidirectional, so you would need *two* of them for *every* connected client, and you gain no advantages over Unix sockets.